# When i search a record on All Subscribers list, where can i find the unsub reason?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, query, sql, sfmc-business-unit

I am searching for a record in All Subscribers list in parent BU (no child BU exits).

When i search in this list , i  find a record showing the following window:

1. Where in this window/tabs can i know the Unsubscribe Reason?

[image]

2. why does the history tab give me stats that the recipient opened an email on 15 August 2022 when he is unsubscribed from all emails comms?
   why does the data not match?
3. How do i query on a parent BU on All Subscribers list?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the answers to your questions:

1. Unfortunately, you cannot see the unsubscribe reason on the subscriber record. You can either see it on the collective list of All Subscribers:

[image]

Or you need to run an SQL query against the [_BusinessUnitUnsubscribes](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_businessunitunsubscribes.htm&type=5) data view to be able to see it. Here is an example query:

```
SELECT
SubscriberKey,
UnsubDateUTC,
UnsubReason
FROM _BusinessUnitUnsubscribes
```

2. No idea why that would happen - this is very odd and I'd create a support case and ask Salesforce support to investigate it.
3. Depends on what information you are trying to get. Some basic data cen be gathered from the [_ListSubscribers](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_listsubscribers.htm&type=5) data view, but if you want the custom attributes, you will have to join it with the [_EnterpriseAttribute](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_enterpriseattribute.htm&type=5) data view. Here's a basic query, in which you'd have to replace the list id with the id of your All Subscribers list:

```
SELECT 
EmailAddress,
SubscriberKey
FROM ent._ListSubscribers 
WHERE ListID = 123
```